# MySQL curdate() return current date minus 17 days

Tags: mysql, date

I use MySQL Workbench 8.0.
I have created a mysql database with docker.
Since few weeks, if I try the following commands (for example today the 1st september 2020):

`SELECT CURDATE()` or `SELECT NOW()`, the return is:

> 2020-08-15 or 2020-08-15 20:17:45

I don't understand why, so i've tried:
`SELECT @@SYSTEM_TIME_ZONE, @@TIME_ZONE, NOW();`

and I get:

> UTC,  SYSTEM, 2020-08-15 20:17:45

I thinck it's not a timezone issue but I have no ideas about what is going wrong.
Thanck you

Comment: By default Docker use UTC, you can pass an environment variable to change it, try it. docker run -e TZ=Europe/Amsterdam

Comment: I have tried it and it's doesn't work. 
The difference between the current date and the returned date is 17 days